# How to use whereHas on multilevel relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How to use **whereHas** on multilevel relationship like:

```
$parentCats = Category::with(
    'children',
    'children.products',
    'children.products.productDetails'
);
```

Now I want to do query like:

```
$parentCats = $parentCats->whereHas(
    'children.products.productDetails',
    function ($q2) use ($size) {
        $q2->where('size', '=', $size);
    }
)->find($id);
```

this query is giving all data. But I want data only where **productDetails** have given size.

Comment: Your code looks right. It doesn't filter on product_details.size you say?

Comment: I just tested a `whereHas` on a similar situation I had and it works fine and I didn't do anything really different from you.  Keep an eye on your sql general log and see if you can spot anything happening there which might cause this.

Comment: I am still getting all data, I have no idea why it is not working. It's not filtering product_details.size, neither any other property of product_details.

Comment: One more thing if there is not related model data for any parent model then it is giving perperty of non object error, how to check before querying in this kind of relationship. @Jaw.sh